# Mac vs. Windows JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, css, windows, html, macos

I'm trying to create an image slider with fades.  Each set of code I find online works in Mac/Safari only, but not in Mac/Chrome or Mac/Firefox.  I tried on Windows and it works in Windows/Chrome and Windows/Firefox, but not Windows/IE.  Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  I also wanted to add some popup peekaboos (captions) with my images.  Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color:black;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:850px;
height:300px;

}
img{
-moz-transition-property: opacity;
-moz-transition-duration: 3s;
-webkit-transition-property:opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
position:absolute;
width: 850px;
height:300px
}
img.fade-out{opacity:0}
img.fade-in{opacity:1}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="Image1.jpg"/>
<img src="Image2.jpg"/>
<img src="Image3.jpg"/>
<img src="Image4.jpg"/>
<script>
var interval = 4 * 20; // Seconds between change
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imageArray = [];
var imageCount = images.length;
var current = 0;

var randomize = function(){
return (Math.round(Math.random() * 3 - 1.5));
}
for(var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++){
images[i].className = 'fade-out';
imageArray[i] = images[i];
}
imageArray.sort(randomize);

var fade = function(){

imageArray[current++].className = 'fade-out';
if(current == imageCount){
current = 0;
imageArray.sort(randomize);
}
imageArray[current].className = 'fade-in';

setTimeout(fade, interval * 100);
};
fade();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this, with actual images?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late!  I don't know how jsFiddle works, but I did manage to figure out my error.  Very silly on my end.  Thank you!

Comment: Oh, OK. Still, if it's the same error that causes different behaviour between Safari and Chrome, I'd be interested in hearing about it. (It's a hobby of mine to collect errors that makes browsers act differently.)